# How to solve this circuit using mesh analysis?

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5U85l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
                                                                                                            How would I solve this circuit using mesh analysis? I can't make a supermesh because I would then have to know the voltage across the independent current source and I can't have 2 meshes because I have a dependent current source.

Comment: By KCL at the top right node \$I_1 = 1\text{A} = 3i_x + i_x = 4i_x\$ so \$i_x = 0.25\$A.

Comment: @Null Well that works for this circuit, but if this circuit was part of a larger circuit that had several more meshes you wouldn't be able to solve it using KCL directly. You would have to create the loop currents. So is there a way to solve this by setting up equations involving KVL and loop currents?

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Comment: @LeonHeller What do you mean no attempt at a solution? I did attempt it, and what I came up with is in the post... I tried a supermesh and 2 meshes and I listed the problems with that in the post.

Comment: You can do a supermesh, but then you still need to define that supermesh current in terms of the dependent current source as the supermesh current branches into the dependent source and R2.

Comment: And you can use that relationship of their currents to compute the voltage drop across them, and then you use that drop in the KVL if you are opposed to deriving so directly in KCL.

Comment: Is your dependent source meant to be a CCCS or a VCCS? The symbol indicates a VCCS, but the equation indicates CCCS.

Answer (score 2):

> How would I solve this circuit using mesh analysis?

I assume the controlled source is a CCCS.

The left most clockwise mesh current, \$i_a\$ is by inspection \$i_a = 1A\$.

Clearly, the right most clockwise mesh current is just \$i_b = i_x\$.  But \$i_b\$ cannot be found by KVL (as you've pointed out) so we need an auxiliary constraint to replace the KVL equation.

That constraint is given by the controlled source:

$$i_a - i_b = 3i_x = 3i_b  \Rightarrow i_b = \frac{i_a}{4} = 0.25A = i_x$$

Remarkably, the solution does not depend on the resistor values.